# How do I change the size and position of text area in Rails app using simple_form_for?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have created a form in my rails app using the Simple Form Gem. 3 of the 14 fields are text area input fields (fields 4, 5 and 6). When the form is displayed, however, there is some unexpected behaviour; most of the fields appear in the correct order vertically as expected but the 3 text area fields all appear right in the middle of the screen and, in fact partially cover fields 2 and 3. the width is also more than the width of the screen, which causes a scroll bar to appear at the bottom of the page. They should be small text area input fields each in the correct order following the other input fields. Below I have listed my attempts to solve the issue.

I am using rails 5.1.5 and ruby 2.2.6. In addition I am using Bootstrap 3.

here is the form partial _form.html.erb.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@questionnaire) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :dob %>
    <%= f.input :q1 %>
    <%= f.input :q2 %>
    <%= f.input :q3 %>
#3 fields below are causing the problems (q4, q5, q6)
    <%= f.input :q4 %>
    <%= f.input :q5 %>
    <%= f.input :q6 %>

    <%= f.input :q7 %>
    <%= f.input :q8 %>
    <%= f.input :q9 %>
    <%= f.input :q10 %>
    <%= f.input :q11 %>
    <%= f.input :q12 %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180516082217) do

  create_table "questionnaires", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.date "dob"
    t.string "q1"
    t.string "q2"
    t.string "q3"
    t.text "q4"
    t.text "q5"
    t.text "q6"
    t.boolean "q7"
    t.boolean "q8"
    t.boolean "q9"
    t.integer "q10"
    t.integer "q11"
    t.integer "q12"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

I have tried many things to try to alter the size and position of the text area. I managed to alter the height using

```
<%= f.input :q4, as: :text, input_html: {rows: 10, cols: 10}  %>
```

however, this had no effect on either the width or position, but did change the height
I also tried adding my own css changing the view to:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@questionnaire) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.error_notification message: f.object.errors[:base].to_sentence if f.object.errors[:base].present? %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :dob %>
    <%= f.input :q1 %>
    <%= f.input :q2 %>
    <%= f.input :q3 %>
 </div>

 <div class="test">
    <%= f.input :q4 %>
    <%= f.input :q5 %>
    <%= f.input :q6 %>
 </div>

 <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :q7 %>
    <%= f.input :q8 %>
    <%= f.input :q9 %>
    <%= f.input :q10 %>
    <%= f.input :q11 %>
    <%= f.input :q12 %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and the in the questionnaires.scss

```
.test
{
width: 300px;
height: auto;
}
```

I partially solved the positioning problem by changing

```
<%= f.input :q4 %>
```

to:

```
<%= f.input :q4, as: :string %>
```

this solves positioning and all fields are in the correct order and position, but now the input is a string input (a single line) and I would prefer to have a text input for these fields. what could be causing the text_area inputs to appear in the middle of the screen and not respond to the changes i have made?  I can't think of any more solutions now so would appreciate any new perspectives.

EDIT: HTML produced by the faulty form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrapp3</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Bootstrapp3">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-d2524d97bf4870944294b74c7946b5c906e242a64430eba3b848a35f540a6bc4.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/1st_load_framework.self-7ba93f5c54e2609dc56add26ceaa59022bd2ba0732f4cb166c1a4e5c403039e4.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/slide_show.self-4df0b8ec94d4a18b8649e9fa49695c40b8ba8e8eee05dc626c8098e25f5f88b7.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/custom.self-82abd4a5838a43d3c64acce597602498accb1f77044da752ff13fe94fbd5c47c.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/rails-ujs.self-8944eaf3f9a2615ce7c830a810ed630e296633063af8bb7441d5702fbe3ea597.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-2db6ec539b9190f75e1d477b305df53d12904d5cafdd47c7ffd91ba25cbec128.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.self-6ad2488465135ab731a045a8ebbe3ea2fc501aed286042496eda1664fdd07ba9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.self-742145c5bb847aafdadc6e339be795628f8bc25f177e851f03a8c42278eb0312.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/button.self-126ac9bf0e7f2d8568f8da3a00fd5f0fac6eae0946331003370161fbf8d7975e.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.self-e47323f363ceb3dc0bdbce05e36e709ed428e339833a41140a85cb0af24b8127.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.self-2eb697f62b587bb786ff940d82dd4be88cdeeaf13ca128e3da3850c5fcaec301.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.self-561cca1cbaf67474e01e9536f106bad541594860a6df997004591c1c1957a147.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-3e78617ade5663314b7ee0ea10375a5b34d59ffbade44939e3f2a4e4ef2019b3.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.self-5bf7078b682f8b131332eefa46b45fa5eff2eca745fc0d03e2991450888f7c28.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.self-6d6f1a7fc5c8aabf3547fa1b794fab6268f54bc55ad815e55873c71f52513517.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-969f3c5f48cdf1e439c7fa1154c13b948715f5c689f87837c0b64521d3b46ef6.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.self-05afb177e08f98997ccfc84fa08a215e4b27d48d5fe4d049080675e9dffd8199.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.self-0aa93860b59fe7393f1dd490f54b3cb994f9d6155adffce034d4e14ae361b041.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.self-fbfa5ad7d9aa0afe439ec4ff3883acc4cb92b62cb67c40d674320c9aa1d4642d.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/action_cable.self-69fddfcddf4fdef9828648f9330d6ce108b93b82b0b8d3affffc59a114853451.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/cable.self-8484513823f404ed0c0f039f75243bfdede7af7919dda65f2e66391252443ce9.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/custom.self-797e6622a3c28029f3bcb1f4583be5560baa026079e90f8b18715e073cc58369.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/google_analytics.self-6388a897c429fdec3c71a1c7e52e25d012c306c14abc4dc6b943586cb9ab8287.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/questionnaires.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-12be097b9a2442b0b6cdcb5146d1d63c00abcde3675ff34d1de6126cb13e6714.js?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
<meta name="csrf-token" content="yGch+Mj/lnQ/fDuyaaDTw6wQPBsMjP+OkOQPqyg+du/saJ33BjyzSJULLTq21o3gZVwiuTr6arbroFUK4cOfYw==" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bar" >
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Inicio</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="/pages/about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="/pages/page1">Skankometer</a></li>
<li><a href="/pages/page2">Page2</a></li>
<li><a href="/pages/contacto">Contacto</a></li>
<li><a href="/questionnaires/new">Questionnaire</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

    </header>
    <main role="main">

       <h1>New Questionnaire</h1>


<form novalidate="novalidate" class="simple_form new_questionnaire" id="new_questionnaire" action="/questionnaires" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="/bcZJCZ7UPxmLMpdbFevb+GCt69ylgmtdAJgAOZmeZQThlyu8SDMj9hKOu7RVI3cOyUYoDaE1dwryZIs8xEkTw==" />



  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="form-group string optional questionnaire_name"><label class="form-control-label string optional" for="questionnaire_name">Name</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="questionnaire[name]" id="questionnaire_name" /></div>
    <div class="form-group date optional questionnaire_dob"><label class="form-control-label date optional" for="questionnaire_dob_1i">Dob</label><div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center"><select id="questionnaire_dob_1i" name="questionnaire[dob(1i)]" class="form-control mx-1 date optional">
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018" selected="selected">2018</option>
<option value="2019">2019</option>
<option value="2020">2020</option>
<option value="2021">2021</option>
<option value="2022">2022</option>
<option value="2023">2023</option>
</select>
<select id="questionnaire_dob_2i" name="questionnaire[dob(2i)]" class="form-control mx-1 date optional">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5" selected="selected">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select id="questionnaire_dob_3i" name="questionnaire[dob(3i)]" class="form-control mx-1 date optional">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16" selected="selected">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
</div></div>
    <div class="form-group string optional questionnaire_q1"><label class="form-control-label string optional" for="questionnaire_q1">Q1</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="questionnaire[q1]" id="questionnaire_q1" /></div>
    <div class="form-group string optional questionnaire_q2"><label class="form-control-label string optional" for="questionnaire_q2">Q2</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="questionnaire[q2]" id="questionnaire_q2" /></div>
    <div class="form-group string optional questionnaire_q3"><label class="form-control-label string optional" for="questionnaire_q3">Q3</label><input class="form-control string optional" type="text" name="questionnaire[q3]" id="questionnaire_q3" /></div>

    <div class="form-group text optional questionnaire_q4"><label class="form-control-label text optional" for="questionnaire_q4">Q4</label><textarea class="form-control text optional" name="questionnaire[q4]" id="questionnaire_q4">
</textarea></div>
    <div class="form-group text optional questionnaire_q5"><label class="form-control-label text optional" for="questionnaire_q5">Q5</label><textarea class="form-control text optional" name="questionnaire[q5]" id="questionnaire_q5">
</textarea></div>
    <div class="form-group text optional questionnaire_q6"><label class="form-control-label text optional" for="questionnaire_q6">Q6</label><textarea class="form-control text optional" name="questionnaire[q6]" id="questionnaire_q6">
</textarea></div>

    <fieldset class="form-group boolean optional questionnaire_q7"><div class="form-check"><input name="questionnaire[q7]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input class="form-check-input boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="questionnaire[q7]" id="questionnaire_q7" /><label class="form-check-label boolean optional" for="questionnaire_q7">Q7</label></div></fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group boolean optional questionnaire_q8"><div class="form-check"><input name="questionnaire[q8]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input class="form-check-input boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="questionnaire[q8]" id="questionnaire_q8" /><label class="form-check-label boolean optional" for="questionnaire_q8">Q8</label></div></fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group boolean optional questionnaire_q9"><div class="form-check"><input name="questionnaire[q9]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input class="form-check-input boolean optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="questionnaire[q9]" id="questionnaire_q9" /><label class="form-check-label boolean optional" for="questionnaire_q9">Q9</label></div></fieldset>
    <div class="form-group integer optional questionnaire_q10"><label class="form-control-label integer optional" for="questionnaire_q10">Q10</label><input class="form-control numeric integer optional" type="number" step="1" name="questionnaire[q10]" id="questionnaire_q10" /></div>
    <div class="form-group integer optional questionnaire_q11"><label class="form-control-label integer optional" for="questionnaire_q11">Q11</label><input class="form-control numeric integer optional" type="number" step="1" name="questionnaire[q11]" id="questionnaire_q11" /></div>
    <div class="form-group integer optional questionnaire_q12"><label class="form-control-label integer optional" for="questionnaire_q12">Q12</label><input class="form-control numeric integer optional" type="number" step="1" name="questionnaire[q12]" id="questionnaire_q12" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Create Questionnaire" class="btn" data-disable-with="Create Questionnaire" />
  </div>
</form>

<a href="/questionnaires">Back</a>

    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please add produced form html?

Comment: @Vasilisa added html output for faulty page

Comment: Look OK. Check, maybe you have rules for textarea somewhere in custom css files?

Comment: @Vasilisa i was thinking that it could be some conflict with bootstrap default setttings, but do you know how i can see the bootstrap default settings? because they are all hidden it is impossible to know which setting to override in the custom css file. bootstrap is positioning the text area in the wrong place and at the wrong size.

Comment: For Chrome: right mouse click - Inspect - Computed tab in Elements section - unfold needed css property (width for example) - you can see all files that affects this property. One more guess about your problem - maybe it is because of incorrect order of css files in your application.css? Which gem do you use for bootstrap including?

Comment: @Vasilisa bootstrap-sass gem is used in my Gemfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After right-clicking on the web page and using the "inspect" function in order to see the HTML I was able to see that the text-area element inherited a css class called ".text" here the property "position" was set to "absolute" (or set relative to the containing block). changing this property to "static" solved the issue.

adding my own .text css class to my custom.css.scss file as follows overrode the .text css class that it was taking this property from

```
.text {
  position: static;
}
```